# How to download a file in a shell script after connecting to another server via ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, download

**My goal:**

having a shellscript for a cronjob (on MacOSX Snow Leopard) that connects to a Debian machine with ssh (public/private key login), executes a `tar` command and downloads the tarred file afterwards.

**My problem:**

The login works, also the execution of some commands. But how can I download a file back to the local machine?

**This is what I have so far:**

This is the content of the shell script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remotehost << 'ENDSSH'
tar -C / -czf /home/user/stuff.tar.gz /home/user/stuff
ENDSSH
```

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун: Because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I cannot test that immediately, but try to: "scp user@debian_machine:/path_to_tar /path/to/local/folder"

Comment: So it means I should close the ssh connection and launch scp within my script afterwards?

Comment: @acme: There is absolutely no need to do so.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: No need, but if the data isn't going to change much between runs, there may be a benefit in closing the connection and then running `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple, no heredoc needed.

```
ssh -Te none user@remotehost "tar -C / -cz /home/user/stuff" >stuff.tar.gz
```

Comment: Nifty! Thanks a lot. I'll mark this as the accepted answer as it also contains some script improvements for better reading ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Stream it back.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remotehost << 'ENDSSH' > stuff.tar.gz
tar -C / -czf - /home/user/stuff
ENDSSH
```

Comment: I'll give jørgensen the accepted answer as he made a good improvement hint I use now, though your answer was the first one with the nifty streaming idea coming up. Hope you don't mind. A shame there can't be two answers marked as accepted ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this might be want you want.

`scp stuff.tar.gz user@remotehost:/"directory to place this file"/`

Comment: Thanks, I already thought about something like this but the solution using stdout without an additional connection is a little bit more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Simply [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) the file once it's created:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remotehost tar -C / -czf /home/user/stuff.tar.gz /home/user/stuff
rsync -chavP --stats user@remotehost:/home/user/stuff.tar.gz .
```

This *does* initiate a second connection to `remotehost` but will save you copying data across the network when the file has not changed (much) since the last time it was archived.

Answer (score 1):

Why downloading the tar file and not create the tar content on stdout?

Ie:

```
ssh user@machine '(' cd /the/dir '&&' tar cf - list of files ')' >archive.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

I. How to compress files or folders via SSH

For different compressed formats, you need to use different command lines:

1. Zip

To compress a file or folder to a zip file:

```
zip -r file.zip file
```

2. Bz2

To compress a file (ONLY) to a bz2 file:

```
Bzip2 -zk file
```

3. Gz

To compress a file (ONLY) to a gz file:

```
gzip -c file > file.gz
```

By the way, you need to change the above "file" to the file name with extension (if any) you want to compress, while you can replace the following "xxx" with any keywords:

4. Tar

To compress one file or folder to a tar file:

```
tar -cvf xxx.tar file
```

To compress multiple files and/or folders to a tar file:

```
tar -cvf xxx.tar file1 file2 folder1 folder2 ...
```

5. Tar.bz2

To compress one file or folder to a tar.bz2 file:

```
tar -cvjf xxx.tar.bz2 file
```

To compress multiple files and/or folders to a tar.bz2 file:

```
tar -cvjf xxx.tar.bz2 file1 file2 folder1 folder2 ...
```

6. Tar.gz

To compress one file or folder to a tar.gz file:

```
tar -cvzf xxx.tar.gz file
```

To compress multiple files and/or folders to a tar.gz file:

```
tar -cvzf xxx.tar.gz file1 file2 folder1 folder2 ...
```

II. How to extract file via SSH

To extract a file will be easier, since you don't need to worry about folders:

1. Zip

To extract a zip file:

```
unzip file.zip
```

2. Bz2

To extract a bz2 file:

```
bunzip2 file.bz2
```

3. Gz

To extract a gz file:

```
gzip -d file.gz
```

4. Tar

To extract a tar file:

```
tar -xvf file.tar
```

5. Tar.bz2

To extract a tar.bz2 file:

```
tar -xvjf file.tar.bz2
```

6. Tar.gz

To extract a tar.gz file:

```
tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
```

By the way, you need to replace the above "file"s of the compressed files with the real file names.

Bonus:

Besides remote servers, the above command lines are also available for a Mac OS computer with the Terminal application.